# Kendo UI charts in code behind

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart, kendo-angular-ui

In my angular 5 project I want to add a directive that would add a navigation pane to any chart it is attached. To do that I need to add a pane, category axis, value axis and some series to the chart dynamically in directive code. How can I do that? I tried to add it in different hooks such as ngAfterContentInit but to no avail. What is general strategy for such things?

The code:

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  AfterContentInit,
  OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ChartComponent,
  PaneComponent,
  CategoryAxisItemComponent,
  ValueAxisItemComponent,
  SeriesItemComponent,
  CategoryAxisLabelsComponent,
  CategoryAxis,
  ValueAxis
} from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CollectionService } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts/dist/es2015/common/collection.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appChartNaviagation]'
})
export class ChartNaviagationDirective implements AfterContentInit {

  private navigationMin = new BehaviorSubject<Date>(undefined);

  private navigationMax = new BehaviorSubject<Date>(undefined);

  constructor(private chart: ChartComponent) {

  }

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {

    const navigationPane = new PaneComponent(this.chart.configurationService, new CollectionService());
    navigationPane.name = 'navigator';
    navigationPane.height = 100;
    this.chart.panes.push(navigationPane);

    const navigationCategoryAxis = new CategoryAxisItemComponent(this.chart.configurationService, new CollectionService());
    navigationCategoryAxis.name = 'navigatorCategories';
    navigationCategoryAxis.pane = 'navigator';
    this.chart.categoryAxis = [
      this.chart.categoryAxis as CategoryAxis || new CategoryAxisItemComponent(this.chart.configurationService, new CollectionService()),
      navigationCategoryAxis
    ];        
    const mainAxis = <CategoryAxisItemComponent>this.chart.categoryAxis[0];

    const navigationValueAxis = new ValueAxisItemComponent(this.chart.configurationService, new CollectionService());
    navigationCategoryAxis.name = 'navigationValues';
    navigationCategoryAxis.pane = 'navigator';
    const axisLabels = new CategoryAxisLabelsComponent(this.chart.configurationService);
    axisLabels.visible = false;
    navigationCategoryAxis.labels = axisLabels;

    this.chart.valueAxis = [
      this.chart.valueAxis as ValueAxis || new ValueAxisItemComponent(this.chart.configurationService, new CollectionService()),
      navigationValueAxis
    ];        

    if (this.navigationData) {
      const naviagationSeries = new SeriesItemComponent(this.chart.configurationService, undefined);
      naviagationSeries.type = 'area';
      naviagationSeries.line = { style: 'smooth' };
      naviagationSeries.data = this.navigationData;
      naviagationSeries.field = 'value';
      naviagationSeries.categoryField = 'time';
      naviagationSeries.axis = 'navigationValues';
      naviagationSeries.categoryAxis = 'navigatorCategories';
      naviagationSeries.aggregate = 'sumOrNull';

      this.chart.series.push(naviagationSeries);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm expecting to achieve the same behaviour as described [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/chart/elements/selection/#toc-using-selection-as-navigator).

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Right now it's quite hard to comment or reproduce the steps you have taken.

Comment: Consider reviewing this article and then editing your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask